# How to get Java applets working with Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, java

I use Gotomypc which is either a Java applet or an App.

The Gotomypc applet will launch under Firefox or Safari but not Chrome. When I launch the app under chrome I get the yellow status bar at the top that says:

*"Java is required for some elements on this page".*

When I click the install button it simply takes me to this generic page http://java.com/en/download/apple_manual.jsp

How to get Java applets working with Chrome?

Answer (score 7):

Currently, on a 64-bit Mac (such as >=10.8) with Java 7 you cannot use Java Applets in Chrome.

Java 7 is 64 bit only, and as such requires a 64 bit browser. Chrome on Mac is currently only 32 bit.

The Chrome/Chromium developers have a bug to show progress, although actual work seems to have stalled for some reason.: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115774

If you wish to use an older version that will work (not recommended due to security issues) you can follow these steps, assuming you still have java 6 installed: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559 (summarised below)

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled
sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
```

To undo these steps

```
sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws
```

Followed by downloading the latest Java from Oracle.

Comment: If you want to track the efforts to carry Chromium Mac builds into the 64 bit age, star this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18323

Answer (score 0):

If you open any application that requires Java or run `java` in a shell, OS X will show a dialog about installing the Java runtime environment.

[image]

I tried [Oracle's JRE 7 installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and [Apple's old Java update for Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5267) first, but neither got rid of those dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an easy way to install java through terminal.

Launch Terminal from /Applications/Utilities/ and type the following:

```
java -version
```

Hit enter and if java is not installed you'll get a message that reads "No Java runtime present, requesting install" followed by an alert requesting you to install java runtime. Click "install" to install the latest version of Java for your device.

Comment: This does install java but does not allow it to run in Chrome whichis the question here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I downloaded Mountain Lion an chrome would not run Java.

I found this fix to get Java 6 insted of Java 7, that does not run on chrome:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

Comment: Whilst your answer may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference

Answer (score 0):

Reenabling the Java 6 plugins as outlined above and in http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559 worked for Firefox, but not for Chrome or Safari.

As per the Apple Support document, these are the steps to fix Firefox:

> 1. Open Terminal, located in the Utilities folder.
>      Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key: 
>      `sudo mkdir -p /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled`
> 2. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:
>      `sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled`
> 3. Enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:
>      `sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`
> 4. To re-enable Java SE 6 Web Start, enter this command, then press the Return or Enter key:
>      `sudo ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws /usr/bin/javaws`

Answer (score -1):

Mac OS X has their own Java. You can install it here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5267

After installing it, restart your Chrome and it should be ready to go!

Comment: The installer is for 10.7. I don't know about applets, but I couldn't use Java applications even after running it.

Comment: It says 10.7 or later.

Comment: "This release is for OS X Lion versions 10.7 or later." might also mean 10.7.0 up to 10.7.x. In any case, I couldn't use Java applications after running that installer and had to install the JRE from the Software Update dialog.

Answer (score -1):

After you install Java, search for Java Preferences and you can check the option to 'Enable applet plug-in and web-start applications'

Comment: What do you mean 'search'? Search where?

Comment: On System Preferences. Search for Java and you'll get the configuration panel you're looking for